# Update value with days value from another table - mysql

Tags: mysql

I would need to update the value from a table , taking the days value from another one:

```
orders:
        pid     status
=========== ==========
          1          5
          2          5
          3          4

post:
pid               days 
========== =========== 
         3          30
```

I would need that after 30 days in this case (value from post table) status for pid 3 updates to 5.
How could I get this done?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you be more specific? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Given**

The "days" field in the post table is a datetime datatype.

**The Code** - [See demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/06dcd/1/0)

```
update orders o inner join post p on p.pid = o.pid  
set status = 5
where DATEDIFF(p.days,CURDATE()) < -29;
```

**Code Explanation**

After joining the two tables, the where statement is used to identify
   all pids with 30+ days.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and sorry for not explaining myself correctly. When a new order id is inserted, REAL TIME starts. Now days from post table should be days that are running in countdown I guess, so basically what is needed is that after 30 real days since a new Id in orders was inserted, the status in order changes from 4 to 5. In this case are 30 days, but it could be any other value, and days are real time..

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  The code and demo have been updated accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much! I adapted your queries a little bit, and it works! Thank you, have a nice day